# AWS configuration - Cloudfront handling SSL for EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

I have a Cloudfront distribution, with an attached ssl certificate. I want to use it to proxy requests to an EC2 instance running Gunicorn.

Currently, I have the ec2 instance listening on some random port (HTTP), with the cloudfront distribution pointing to its *private* ip, but that doesn't seem to be working. The site is unaccessible via cloudfront, but *can* be accessed on its public ip (on the correct port). Clearly this is the opposite of what I want.

I want only cloudfront to be publicly accessible (redirect http to https), and the ec2 instance to only be accessible via cloudfront.

Should I in fact be using a load balancer for this, instead of cloudfront, and pointing route53 to that instead?

Comment: `Should I in fact be using a load balancer for this, instead of cloudfront, and pointing route53 to that instead?` - Yes.

Comment: @jweyrich Would you mind explaining? I'm sure you're right, but I'd like to learn a bit more so that I can understand it myself

Comment: The fact that you have multiple servers - supposedly serving the same content - means you are better off using an ELB or ALB. Keep in mind you're balancing load and doing SSL termination. You may configure one distribution per origin in CloudFront, but that doesn't make much sense unless those origins serve different content (from each other). You can still point your CloudFront origin to the ALB/ELB.

Comment: @jweyrich Oh, sorry, no, just one ec2 instance, and unlikely to be more of them. There are no multiple servers

Comment: My bad - misread your Q. CloudFront cannot access private IPs. The origin is required to have a publicly accessible IP. You may add some restrictions to your webserver configuration, like filtering by HTTP header contents, but there's no guarantee someone won't bypass that at some point. Just don't publish your endpoint to anyone.

Comment: @jweyrich Ok, and how does that work in terms of ssl? Do both the cloudfront distro, and the ec2 server require the certificate?

Comment: You can do SSL termination in CloudFront. No need to use SSL in your EC2, unless you want private communication between them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190871/discussion-between-alex-and-jweyrich).